# Azure log stream viewer without the console one

Tags: azure, logging, stream

There is any viewer for seeing azure log stream without the console one.
I mean that is there any realtime log viewer app for azure web app service?
I do not know, how people are diagnosis live azure app service.

I need to diagnosis live azure app service by logging. So, I need a real time log viewer that has an UI like Log4View.

Comment: When you say "the console one", are you saying the kudu console? <sitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net

Comment: the log stream write in an azure web console

Answer (score 1):

Use Nlog and send all logs to a specific machine with a real ip, then see the log using Log4View from that machine.

Answer (score 0):

Enable diagnosis should do it for you.

Comment: Basically, I need a log viewer like Log4View.

Comment: you mean Application insights

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a [debugger in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio), or you can use [log stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log).